# Allocating and freeing memory inside loop in C

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks

I have a question about how to make a temporary string in C.  What I mean is I would like to create a string on every iteration step and free the variable after it is not useful anymore.
I have seen question similar to this one, but they differ in significant ways.

So right now I have something similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    //aray1 and array2 are arrays of strings
    char* temporary_value = make_hash(array1[i], array2[i], size[i]);
    if (is_valid(temporary_value)) {
       //Code, that doesn't interferate in memory, but uses temporary_value - mostly just compare to it
    }
    free(temporary_value);
 }
```

Where make_hash mallocs the memory depending on size[i].

But it feels so wrong and sometimes returns segment fault.
My ideas to improve this are:

- Make string array and free it after the loop
- Put "make_hash" code inside the for-loop and just realloc memory during iteration and free the temporary_value after the for-loop

But these solutions seem to be also bad.  How would you approach this kind of problem?

Comment: Can you know at the time this loop is executed the maximum possible size passed as argument to `make_hash`?

Comment: Thank guys for your time, especially for you @dedecos, as array is not so big I decided to iterate it one more time and get the maximum possible size, allocate memory for variable before loop and free it afterwards  :)

Comment: Hope I could help (: You want me to create an answer or you already got it?

Comment: Already got it, thank you :)

Comment: If performance is important, `malloc`/`free` every time though the loop is probably going to be wasteful.

Comment: If `make_hash()` always allocates memory and isn't changeable, then the code you've got is as good as it gets.  If you can modify `make_hash()` so it is passed some (allocated) memory to use, but it is passed in such a way that the allocation can be changed, then you could reduce the amount of allocation and freeing.  Look at the interface to POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) for a standard example of how you could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When functions return objects of a known size, it is often better to let the caller handle allocations than the functions themselves, the caller often know what kind of allocation is best (automatic, static, heap, etc..). Just pass the pointer to where you want the result when calling the function.

Hash functions often returns hashes of fixed size, so i would go for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    char buffer[HASH_SIZE];

    /*
       `make_hash` writes result into `buffer` and returns `buffer` on success, or
        `NULL` on error
    */
    char* temporary_value = make_hash(buffer, array1[i], array2[i], size[i]);
    if (is_valid(temporary_value)) {
       //Code, that doesn't interferate in memory, but uses temporary_value - mostly just compare to it
    }
 }
```

In case your hash function *does not* return a fixed-size hash value, and you want the possibility to `realloc` your buffer, then pass a pointer to a pointer to your buffer, together to a pointer to a variable holding the buffer size:

```
make_hash(char **buffer, size_t *buffer_size, const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t s)
{
   size_t new_size = .....;
   if (new_size > *buffer_size)
     {
        char *tmp = realloc(*buffer, new_size);
        if (!tmp)
          return NULL;
        *buffer = tmp;
        *buffer_size = new_size;
     }
   /* 
      Calculate hash, and store it wherever `b` is pointing
    */
    char *b = *buffer;
    .......

    return b; /* or `NULL` on error */
}


char *buffer = NULL;
size_t buffer_size = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {

    char* temporary_value = make_hash(&buffer, &buffer_size, array1[i], array2[i], size[i]);
    if (is_valid(temporary_value)) {
       //Code, that doesn't interferate in memory, but uses temporary_value - mostly just compare to it
    }
 }
 free(buffer);
```

If you have a cheap way of calculating the hash size, without calling `make_hash()` you could also go for the first solution together with a variable-length array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    size_t buffer_size = hash_size(.....);

    char buffer[buffer_size];

    /*
       `make_hash` writes result into `buffer` and returns `buffer` on success, or
        `NULL` on error
    */
    char* temporary_value = make_hash(buffer, array1[i], array2[i], size[i]);
    if (is_valid(temporary_value)) {
       //Code, that doesn't interferate in memory, but uses temporary_value - mostly just compare to it
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this is not freeing within the loop. malloc/free are usually very expensive <s>system</s> calls which you do not want to do if you know that you will have to call malloc again.

The correct way to do this would be malloc once, and then realloc on subsequent calls using the same block of memory, and then free once you're outside the loop.

Comment: Nitpicking: `malloc`/`free` are typically not system calls, but library functions

Comment: @HAL9000 Thank you for the catch, fixed.

Comment: malloc/free are not *that* expensive -- usually much cheaper than a system call.  realloc is also likely to be more expensive than free+malloc if the size changes by much.  As always, you should strive for clarity before worrying too much about performance, and benchmark your code to find the *actual* bottlenecks before worrying about optimizing the wrong things.

Answer (score -2):

The segmentation fault might come from a number of factors, are the arrays the same length, array1, array2 and size. you are also freeing memory without checking if it was allocated.

I will rather have something like this.

```
if (temporary_value != NULL) {
    free(temporary_value);
}
```

It has been long since coding in C but that should help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Checking if argument is `NULL` is pointless as if `NULL` is passed to `free` it will do nothing. However `free`ing an already freed pointer have undefined behavior (so this can be the cause of the segment fault).